# Proving that $A=\{w_{2i}|w_{2i}\not\in L(M_i)\}$ is not Turing-recognizable

Tags: turing-machines

In this problem, $w_{2i}$ is the $2i$th string in the lexicographic order of binary strings and $M_i$ is the TM whose binary code is $w_i$.
We are given the diagonalization language $A_D=\{w_i \mid w_i \notin L(M_i)\}$. We know $A_D$ is not Turing Recognizable.

Basically, $w_i$ is the $i$th string in the following lexicographic ordering:
$\epsilon, 0, 1, 00, 01, 10, 11, ...$

The proof for $A_D$ is the following: Suppose by contradiction, there is a TM $M$ such that $A_D = L(M)$. Then $M=M_i$ with code $w_i$ for some $i$. $w_i \in A_D$ iff $w_i \notin L(M_i)$ by definition of $A_D$. $w_i \in A_D$ iff $w_i \in L(M_i)$ by $A_D = L(M_i)$. A contradiction.

The problem is I don't understand the proof above. Therefore, I have no idea how to approach the topic question. It would be very helpful if someone can give a brief explanation of how $A_D$ proof works and what approach I can take to prove $A$ is not Turing recognizable. For instance, is it possible to reduce $A_D$ to $A$? Or is it better to follow the same proof format as $A_D$?

Comment: What don't you understand about the proof given? Diagonalization is a standard technique that's explained in numerous textbooks and web pages. Without knowing what specifically you don't understand, it's very unlikely that somebody could say anything that would help you, except by blind luck. This kind of general "I don't understand it" question usually requires interaction to make progress. I suggest you go discuss it with your lecturer or TA so you can get the interactive help you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Lets reformat your language $A_D$ to say $A_D=\{ \langle M \rangle| \; \text{M is a Turing machine ( TM ) and does not accept }\langle M \rangle\}$. Here $\langle M \rangle$ means encoding of Turing machine $M$, and I assume the inputs are always valid encodings TM's ( as you can always check if a string is a valid encoding or not ). Now say there was a decider for $A_D$, let it be $D$. Now if you give input $\langle D \rangle $ to $D$ it has to halt ( we assumed it is a decider ) and either reject or accept. If it accepts it, it means $\langle D \rangle  \in A_D$ and thus $D$ does not accept $\langle D \rangle $, which is a contradiction. If $D$ reject $\langle D \rangle $ it means $D$ accepts $\langle D \rangle $ acccording to definition of $A_D$ which again is a contradiction. Either ways it is a contradiction, thus our assumption that $D$ exists is not correct and $A_D$ is undecidable ( this proof is related to [Cantor's diagonal method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) ) .
2. This logic cannot be applied to prove $A_D$ is not  Turing recognizable. I leave the reason for you to figure out ( hint: no assumption about halting on all inputs is made ).
3. I will prove non recognizability  of a general language ( which implies undecidability  ) instead of $A_D$ and the one you specify in your question.

   $L=\{  w | \; f(w) \;\text{ is a valid encoding of some Turing machine where } f \; \text{is some computable function and the Turing machine given by } \; f(w) \; \text{does not accept} \; w\}$ 
   ( $f$ is such that  for every TM encoding $\langle M \rangle \exists w $ s.t. $ f(w)=\langle M \rangle$ )
   Now suppose $L$ was Turing recognizable, let the TM  be $R$. We construct another Turing machine $H$ which given an input $w$ first finds $f(w)$ ( again assuming it is a valid encoding of a TM, if not $H$ can directly reject ). Then $H$ gives $w$ to $R$ and simulates $w$ on $f(w)$ in parallel. If $f(w)$ accepts $w$ $H$ rejects, if $R$ accepts $w$, H accepts. This way you are able to decide language $L$ which is undecidable. You can prove $L$ is undecidable yourself ( see when $f$ is the identity function, $L$ reduces to $A_D$ which is undecidable ).  
   I leave it for you to figure out how non recognizability of $L$ can be used for proving that of your languages.